# Magento Login 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, login

I put my login in my Modal, that automatically pop-up, but it doesnt work on chrome, But when I try in mozilla it works, Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check for any error in cosole

Comment: Im in a developer mode and it doesnt show any error, The Modal show in both browser, What is not working is the magento login, In chrome it just reload the page, In mozilla it works, it brings me to account details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on your local machine and url is http://localhost/magento/ then changed it to http://127.0.0.1/magento/ . You can change this in either core_config_data or from admin.
Many peoples have already faced this problem including my self. Let me know if any other help needed for the same.

Comment: Did it help you @adrian ?